# Recommended way to extend Django auth system

Tags: python, django

django.contrib.auth package is great, but for my project I need to be able to:

- For each role user has I need to be able to specify the department in which he has this role
- For each role I need to be able to specify dashboard_url - the url to which user will be redirected after login and selecting one of available groups.
- For permissions and roles I need to add custom field with description

What is the best way to achieve this?

PS: I use django 1.7

Comment: You may be looking for this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: By the way, the roles you are mentioning are called groups. They are also mentioned in the previous link. :)

Comment: I  looked at this link before - it's  clear how to extend User model, but still have doubt how to extend Group and Permission models - do I have to write my own authentication backend?